# why is it redirecting to the page which is suppose to happen in else clause even when the if statement is true(i feel)

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So in my database, I have 2 nodes  Customer and Driver. And I tried to make the login page in such a way that if the user is in the driver node he goes to the page meant for driver and the same way for the customer. My problem is even when it is Driver it is still going to the customer page.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    progressdialog.show();
    auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(binding.Email.getText().toString(),binding.Password.getText().toString())
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull  Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    progressdialog.dismiss();
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        Toast.makeText(Login_Page.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        String uid = auth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
                        DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
                        DatabaseReference uidRef = rootRef.child("Driver");
                        ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(@NonNull  DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                                if(snapshot.exists()) {
                                    Toast.makeText(Login_Page.this,"LoginDriver",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                                    Intent intent=new Intent(Login_Page.this, HomePage.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                }
                                else {
                                    startActivity(new Intent(Login_Page.this, Custhomepage.class));
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(@NonNull  DatabaseError error) {

                            }
                        };
                        uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
                    }
```

In this code,  When the child is Driver it is supposed to go to the home page but instead, it goes to custhomepage even when the node is in Driver.

This is the database values:

```
    {
      "Users" : {
        "Customer" : {
          "5JEgU9isvdWFop4yt0lGFt9iSEo1" : {
            "mail" : "Ashh@bbyshark.com",
            "password" : "AlexXalexa",
            "username" : "Ashhh"
          },
          "VyxUiy60khMEr4LPsNiKRTIxRs72" : {
            "mail" : "xxx@g.com",
            "password" : "yvuuuuuu",
            "username" : "xxx"
          },
          "aRmz8jnue1NeDeGA08ey9H4rvIJ3" : {
            "mail" : "aa@gmail.co.cin",
            "password" : "123344555",
            "username" : "aa"
          },
          "kgG9GBSK6xVdQUdTKEAnuU3OROv1" : {
            "mail" : "tttt@class.com",
            "password" : "---------------",
            "username" : "j need"
          },
          "pWnRecYxRlQMwUJH5bZ10My5cBi1" : {
            "mail" : "Ashh@babyshark.com",
            "password" : "AlexXalexa",
            "username" : "Ashhh"
          },
          "qHctsriB2GZYzQ2NULw0PmBdCkV2" : {
            "mail" : "arfan@gmail.com",
            "password" : "123456yus",
            "username" : "Arfan"
          }
        },
        "Driver" : {
          "ZMqeFvM4gTh2vjTVu31JQY2jz9x2" : {
            "mail" : "aww@gmail.com",
            "password" : "696969",
            "username" : "aditya"
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: i edited the code now @Hooman

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the JSON from your database (as text, no screenshots please)? You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: okayy i edited now @FrankvanPuffelen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're adding the ValueEventListener to the entire Driver node so it is seeing if a snapshot exists at "Users/Driver" which it does.  Instead the ValueEventListener should be attached to the child node using the UID to check if a snapshot exists at "Users/Driver/{UID}".

Changing this line:

```
DatabaseReference uidRef = rootRef.child("Driver");
```

To this:

```
DatabaseReference uidRef = rootRef.child("Users").child("Driver").child(uid);
```

Should solve the issue.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the 'Driver' and 'Customer' nodes are children of a 'Users' node.  Have updated the answer.